# Conditionally merge lines in text file

Tags: python, list, text, slice

I've a text file full of common misspellings and their corrections.

All misspellings, of the same intended word, should be on the same line.

I do have this somewhat done, but not for all misspellings of the same word.

`misspellings_corpus.txt` (snippet):

```
I'de->I'd
aple->apple
appl->apple
I'ed, I'ld, Id->I'd
```

Desired:

```
I'de, I'ed, I'ld, Id->I'd
aple, appl->apple
```

template: `wrong1, wrong2, wrongN->correct`

---

**Attempt:**

```
lines = []
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/misspellings_corpus.txt', 'r') as fin:
  lines = fin.readlines()

for this_idx, this_line in enumerate(lines):
  for comparison_idx, comparison_line in enumerate(lines):
    if this_idx != comparison_idx:
      if this_line.split('->')[1].strip() == comparison_line.split('->')[1].strip():
        #...
```

```
correct_words = [l.split('->')[1].strip() for l in lines]
correct_words
```

Comment: use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` with a key of your good spelling and append each bad spelling as a value. then once done you can write out the values() and key as you like

Comment: I'm confused by the desired text. Shouldn't the first line be: `I'd, I'd, I'd, I'd`, and the second line also being: `apple, apple`?

Comment: @jrd1 The purpose is to have misspellings separated out by a comma `,`, then `->` correct spelling. I will append desired template to post.

Comment: @JonSG I have now appended a list of `correct_words` to the post. I will look into `collections`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the correct spelling of your words as keys of a dictionary that maps to a set of possible misspellings of that word. The dict is intended for you to easilly find the word you're trying to correct and the set is to avoid duplicates of the misspellings.

```py
possible_misspellings = {}

with open('my-file.txt') as file:
  for line in file:
    misspellings, word = line.split('->')
    word = word.strip()
    misspellings = set(m.strip() for m in misspellings.split(','))

    if word in possible_misspellings:
      possible_misspellings[word].update(misspellings)
    else:
      possible_misspellings[word] = misspellings
```

Then you can iterate over your dictionary

```py
with open('my-new-file.txt', 'w') as file:
  for word, misspellings in possible_misspellings.items():
    line = ','.join(misspellings) + '->' + word + '\n'
    file.write(line)
```

Comment: I'll try this out now and report back. Thank you.

Comment: It works! Tysm. Hypothetically, how might I get rid of duplicate *misspellings* on a line?

Comment: This code should get rid of them too. Notice I'm creating a set from the mispellings in a line, so it won't accept any duplicates  also.

Comment: Ahh ok. Tysm again.

Comment: The key to get rid of duplicates of any kind is using a set instead of a list, since sets are structures that treats elements as things that belong to them or not. Then, when you try to add an element that already is on a set, its state will still be "belong to the set".

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = []
with open('misspellings_corpus.txt', 'r') as fin:
  lines = fin.readlines()
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(list)


for line in lines:
    curr_line = line.split("->")[0].replace(" ","")
    if "," in curr_line:
        for curr in curr_line.split(","):
            my_dict[line.split("->")[1].strip()].append(curr)
    else:
        my_dict[line.split("->")[1].strip()].append(curr_line)

for key, values in my_dict.items():
    print(f"{key} -> {', '.join(values)}")
```